# chart.js - Pie Chart doesn't display all data

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js

I want to create a chart that displays some values in form of a pie. For that I took the Library chart.js. But there is something wrong

I've following JS-Code:

```js
$(function(){
  var ie = 12,
 firefox = 7,
 chrome = 15,
 safari = 13,
 opera = 4,
 chart = $('#chart')[0];
  
   var charObj = new Chart(chart, {
 data: {
     datasets: [{
  data: [
      firefox,
      safari,
      ie,
      opera,
             chrome
  ],
  backgroundColor: [
   "#FF6384",
   "#4BC0C0",
   "#FFCE56",
   "#000",
   "#36A2EB"
  ],
  label: 'Browser' // for legend
 }],
  labels: [
   "Firefox",
   "Safari",
   "Internet Explorer",
   "Opera",
   "Chrome"
  ]
 },
   type: 'polarArea'
 });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.4/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" width="700px" height="700px"></canvas>
```

Why is my Opera Value not being displayed? And when clicking on Opera (at the legend) it hides my Firefox value in the chart?

Comment: Use latest chart.js. i tried with newer version its working. try using https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.bundle.min.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks that your version of chart.js have some bugs. Try using latest version. Example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rp26hv50/). Current version of chart.js is 2.5.0

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script
```